# Setting columns in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im working on a grid in bootstrap, now I have 4 cols in a row, but I need to set it in two rows (each with two columns) when the screen size is set to md (or sm). How I can get that?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="panel panel-blue">This is a column.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
     <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
   </div>
<div class="col">
     <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
   </div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
 </div>
<div class="col">
      <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's already in the Documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#responsive-classes

You can use

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-blue">This is a column.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
     <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
   </div>
<div class="col">
     <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
   </div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-purple">This is a column.</div>     
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```html
<div class="col">
```

use:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
```

Bootstrap uses a 12 column layout by default.

Of course, have a look at the official documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, just setting

```
col-sm-6 col-md-auto
```